# How to ng build src folder to different build folder without overwriting assets of the build folder

Tags: json, angular, nginx, build, assets

Inside our on-prem server we have a 'product' folder from which our nginx runs our frontend.
This product folder contains the build of one of our source folders.
Due to this delegation when we build - our assets folder from our source folder overwrite
our assets folder from our product folder. This is unacceptable because our assets are changeable by our users, for example: our users can edit the i18n translations from an admin panel.

1). We tried changing our angular.json as such:

```
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
            "assets" : []
```

Script

```
ng build  --configuration dev --optimization=false --output-path=E:\path\nginx-1.17.4\html\product
```

The result was that after build assets folder was gone not ignored from overwriting.

2). Then we tried putting the product assets path in the brackets:

```
      "configurations": {
        "dev": {
          "assets": ["../../../product/assets"]
```

Script

```
ng build  --configuration dev --optimization=false --output-path=E:\path\nginx-1.17.4\html\product
```

Only to receive the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: The ../../../product/assets asset path must start with the project source root.
```

3). Then according to [this github thread](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/16979) we tried:

```
  "configurations": {
    "dev": {
      "assets": [{"glob": "**/favicon.png", "input" : "E:/path/nginx-1.17.4/html/product/assets", "output": "assets"}],
```

Same script.

Result - assets folder not present after build.

Is there a way to not overwrite the assets folder when building to a path different from source path?

Specs

```
Angular 13.2.3
Node 14.15.1
OS win32 x64
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Angular CLI build option `--delete-output-path=false`
[Angular CLI ng build options](https://angular.io/cli/build#options)

Comment: Thanks, it does keep the files while building, but result is same. After build is done our assets are being overwritten by the build with previous assets. We want to ignore the assets folder when building.